# How to resolve the fatal error when i try to pull or fetch a git repo

Tags: git, github, fatal-error

I get this error message anytime I try to

> git pull

I get this error message

`fatal error: Cannot fetch both refs/heads/pr/339 and refs/pull/339/head to refs/remotes/origin/pr/339`

I have tried

> git pull --force

tried

> git update-ref -d refs/pull/339/head

> git update-ref -d refs/remotes/origin/pr/339

> git update-ref -d refs/heads/pr/339

I have also tried to prune

> git remote prune origin

Comment: Sounds like a config problem? What is the config (as in `.git/config`) for that remote?

Comment: @eftshift0 is right, you have a configuration error in your `fetch =` settings for remote `origin`. If you include the output of `git config --list --show-origin` we can point out the specific error. I don't have time to write up a proper answer right now.